# How do you get IntelliJ to recognize muliple tiles views.xml?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tiles, spring-roo

I'm using IntelliJ 10 with a Spring Roo project. In the webmvc-config.xml (the spring mvc config context file) IntelliJ allows me to use autocomplete to fill the names of tiles views.  However, it only seems to allow autocomoplete the names of views from WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml it ignores all the views defien din /WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml.   Is there a way to force IntelliJ to recognize these files as tiles config files.

The thing i find annoying about this is that there is an IntelliJ inspection that marks any instance of `<mvc:view-controller path="..." view-name="..."` as an error if it can't find the view refrenced. Now this doesn't actually stop anything from working. But it is annoying. I'm just trying to figure out if this is a bug in IntelliJ or if there is a setting I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [filing the issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-67171) to YouTrack, our developers will investigate it.

Comment: one year since the bug has been reported, please fix it